# Make all grid cells have the width of the widest cell

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

My first question here and your help would be much appreciated

I have a `ul` width `display: grid` inside a `div` with `overflow: hidden`.
The `ul`'s purpose is to function as a slidable element, so its width is not explicitly specified, but rather, defined by its contents. Each `li` element inside the list contains text of variable length, which should not be truncated nor break on a 2nd line.
The `li` count inside the list may vary, from 4 to up to 12 elements.

My question is how can I create a grid that all its cells have the width of the widest `li`? (which, in turn, is defined by the longest text)
Please keep in mind that the grid is always going to have 2 rows

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish:

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fafafa;
    width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 24px;
}

ul {
    overflow: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 8px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

li {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-inline: 12px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 4px;
    align-items: center;
}

a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>text 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Fourth text</a>
        </li>
                <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Test 5 is is a huge text and all other cells should follow its size</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 6</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>This is also a large text</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 8</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 9</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can probably use JS to find the largest width and apply it to all siblings or you just set all the li elements to be the width of the largest one as default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for a css-only solution (provided that it is feasible, of course)

Comment: You cannot properly distribute an element's width in fractions if the element's width is auto.

Comment: @kellyEx I unfortunately don't think there is as far as handling it dynamically. Only css only way I can think of is to set a width to all columns based on the possible widest. Or like I said more involved would be JS to find the widest and set all of them to that. 

I could be wrong though.

Answer (score -3):

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fafafa;
    width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 24px;
}

ul {
    overflow: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 8px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-templates-column: auto auto auto auto; 
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-inline: 12px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 4px;
    align-items: center;
}

a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>text 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Fourth text</a>
        </li>
                <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Test 5 is is a huge text and all other cells should follow its size</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 6</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>This is also a large text</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 8</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 9</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fafafa;
    width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 24px;
}

ul {
    overflow: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 8px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

li {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-inline: 12px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 4px;
    align-items: center;
}

a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>text 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Fourth text</a>
        </li>
                <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Test 5 is is a huge text and all other cells should follow its size</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 6</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>This is also a large text</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 8</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='https://unsplash.it/50/50'>
            <a>Text 9</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer seems useless.